# Rust Non-interactive stdin read

Tags: linux, windows, rust, command-line-interface

I am writing a cli program for rust, what I am trying to achieve feels like it should be simple but is turning out to be a huge hassle. Basically I want to be able to pipe data into the program, however whenever I use `io::stdin` if there is nothing being piped in I get an interactive environment where I have to press enter. Is there anyway to read the entirety of stdin to a string and if there is nothing just move on?

Sorry there is no code snippet but I have got nowhere with this.

Edit 1) Attempted to implement with `atty` but cannot seem to get code working.

```rust
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for line in stdin.lock().lines() {
        if atty::isnt(atty::Stream::Stdin) {
            println!("{}", line.unwrap());
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the ["everything is a file" philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file), there is no easy possibility (beside using of [atty:is](https://docs.rs/atty/0.2.14/atty/)) to distinguish between reading from console/user and reading from a file.

If you do not want any input, you can also redirect the stdin of your program to `/dev/null`:

```sh
  ./the_program < /dev/null
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that `isatty` will only work for unix systems?

Comment: changed link in answer to atty (which is more popular than [isatty](https://docs.rs/crate/isatty/0.1.9) - both support windows.

Comment: have updated my question with my attempt at solving it however is not working

Comment: @seli If you read with ` for line in stdin.lock().lines()` the program always wants to read a line. The terminal only sends complete lines in normal mode, therefore you need press enter. Do the atty check before the for loop if you want not to read at all in the interactive case.